# What does this declare mean?

Tags: ios, objective-c

in the .h file：

```
@interface HitTestTool : NSObject

CGRect HitTestingBounds(CGRect bounds, CGFloat minimumHitTestWidth, CGFloat minimumHitTestHeight);

@end
```

and in the .m file:

```
@implementation HitTestTool

CGRect HitTestingBounds(CGRect bounds, CGFloat minimumHitTestWidth, CGFloat minimumHitTestHeight) {

    CGRect hitTestingBounds = bounds;

    if (minimumHitTestWidth > bounds.size.width) {
        hitTestingBounds.size.width = minimumHitTestWidth;
        hitTestingBounds.origin.x -= (hitTestingBounds.size.width - bounds.size.width)/2;
    }

    if (minimumHitTestHeight > bounds.size.height) {
        hitTestingBounds.size.height = minimumHitTestHeight;
        hitTestingBounds.origin.y -= (hitTestingBounds.size.height - bounds.size.height)/2;
    }

    return hitTestingBounds;
}
```

so i am so confused，is that a Method or a property？ i have never seen this before.

it seems like a method ,but the right format is like:

```
- (void) foo;
```

or a property like :

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) some property;
```

like this ,right?

so what is that way to write CGRect Method?

Comment: This looks like a misplaced declaration (and implementation) of a simple C function. You can freely move it out of `@interface` and `@implementation` blocks.

Comment: looks like a standard ANSI-C function to me, as you know the Objective-C is a subset of ANSI-C, so standard ANSI-C solutions could be quite welcome here.

Comment: @Eimantas thank you

Comment: @holex - *superset

Comment: @Eimantas, oh yeah... such a serious typo :( I need a coffee to wake up properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `CGRect HitTestingBounds(CGRect bounds, CGFloat minimumHitTestWidth, CGFloat minimumHitTestHeight)`; is a function and not a property.

Functions are code blocks that are unrelated to an object/class, just inherited from C. But methods are attached to class/instance(object)